# Cover image under navbar fixed shrinking

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container covering 100% height of my page with a background image. I have a fixed `<navbar>` on scroll but whenever I scroll down my background image jumps up.

I tried adding `padding-top` to the area under the `<navbar>` whenever I begin scrolling but this causes my cover image's height to shrink a bit.

How do I maintain my image's size and remove the jumping on scroll with the fixed `<navbar>`?

```js
$(function() {
  var stickyNavTop = $('.navbar').offset().top;
  var stickyNav = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
      $('.navbar').addClass('sticky');
      $('#landingDiv').addClass('stickyLandingDiv');

    } else {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('sticky');
      $('#landingDiv').removeClass('stickyLandingDiv');
    }
  };

  stickyNav();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyNav();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #191919 !important;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.stickyLandingDiv {
  padding-top: 55px;
}

#landingDiv {
  height: 100%;
}

#landingPageImage {
  background-image: url(/Assets/Images/background6-min.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-menu" id="top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a href="#top" class="nav-link">test</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#item1" class="nav-link">item1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#item2" class="nav-link">item2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#item3" class="nav-link">item3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="landingDiv">
  <div id="landingPageImage">
  </div>
</div>
<section id="about">
  <h1> next page section </h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing it in action but it might have something to do with the navbar going from being in the flow of the page, to out of the flow with `position: fixed` and how that affects the elements on the page that come after. I think you have to either set your navbar to `fixed` or `absolute` to begin with, or set the background div to `absolute` so it isn't being affected. The first option is better if you don't want to have to handle any other elements you add later that could "jump."

Comment: While messing around, It fixed when I set the navbar to fixed from the beginning instead of adding the fixed class to it afterwards. So this was the right answer for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use `sticky`? Is a CSS property works fine in almost of the cases. Try the code bellow. Just change your CSS, I think will work fine:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

/* This piece of code will do the magic */
.header-menu {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #191919 !important;
}

.stickyLandingDiv {
  padding-top: 55px;
}

#landingDiv {
  height: 100%;
}

#landingPageImage {
  background-image: url(/Assets/Images/background6-min.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```